# Maximum size square sub-matrix with all 1s

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

Given a binary matrix, I have find out the maximum size square sub-matrix with all `1`s.

For example, consider the below binary matrix:

```
   0  1  1  0  1 
   1  1  0  1  0 
   0  1  1  1  0
   1  1  1  1  0
   1  1  1  1  1
   0  0  0  0  0
```

The maximum square sub-matrix with all set bits is

```
1  1  1
1  1  1
1  1  1
```

I searched the web for solutions and I found a relation to construct an auxiliary matrix:

```
 If M[i][j] is 1 then
            S[i][j] = min(S[i][j-1], S[i-1][j], S[i-1][j-1]) + 1
         Else /*If M[i][j] is 0*/
            S[i][j] = 0
```

1. Where `M[][]` is the original matrix and `s[][]` is the auxiliary matrix?
2. What does this relation signify?
3. And how is it helpful.

Comment: This is a copy of a question presented on this blog more than two years ago: http://tech-queries.blogspot.com/search/label/Dynamic%20programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a classic Dynamic Programming problem. And u haven't mentioned the entire algorithm which is as follows:

To construct the auxiliary array we have to do the following:

1. First copy the *first row and first column* as it is from M[][] to S[][]
2. And for the remaining entries as u mentioned do the following:

   ```
    If M[i][j] is 1 then
       S[i][j] = min(S[i][j-1], S[i-1][j], S[i-1][j-1]) + 1
    Else /*If M[i][j] is 0*/
       S[i][j] = 0
   ```
3. Find the maximum entry in S[][] and use it to construct the maximum size square submatrix

*What does this relation signify?*

To find the maximum square, we need to find the minimum extension of 1s in different directions and add 1 to it to form the length of square ending at present case.

so as for your case s[][] would be:

```
   0  1  1  0  1
   1  1  0  1  0
   0  1  1  1  0
   1  1  2  2  0
   1  2  2  3  1
   0  0  0  0  0
```

If we just take minimum of these i.e `S[i][j-1], S[i-1][j]` , it takes care of left and top direction.However, we also need to make sure that there are 1's in top left corner of perspective square.
S[i-1][j-1], by definition, contains a max square at position i-1, j-1, whose top left corner ,puts an upper limit on how up and left we can get. So, we need to consider that as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ...and in order to find the maximum all-1s square sub-matrix of M, find the maximum entry in S, e.g. S[i][j]. This entry denotes the lower right corner of the maximum all-1s square sub-matrix of M of size S[i][j].

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in linear time.

Claim:  I can build a data structure in linear time that lets me check, in constant time, whether an arbitrary rectangle is full of 1's.

Proof:  Partial sums; take `S[i][j]` to be the total number of 1's above and to the left of `(i, j)`.  The number of ones in the rectangle between `(a,b)` and `(c,d)`, provided `(a,b)` is above and left of `(c,d)`, is `S[c][d] + S[a][b] - S[a][d] - S[b][c]`.

Now it's a simple scan over the array:

```
size = 1;
For i = 0 to m-size {
  For j = 0 to n-size {
    If S[i+size][j+size] - S[i][j+size] - S[i+size][j] + S[i][j] == size*size {
      size++; j--; continue;
    }
  }
}
```

At the end, `size` is one greater than the largest 1-full square.

Comment: How is the time linear? Wouldn't it be O(n^2) ?

Comment: @WasimThabraze: "Linear" means "linear in the size of the input."  For an n*n grid, the input has n^2 elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can build an extra recursive function which gets as arguments a currect row and col, and looks for a square in any size from it.

From your other function, aftter the extra function returns a value, you have to make 2 calls:
one from (row,col+1) and the other 1 from (row+1,col).

This is a backtracking usage, we check all the options.